# Passing an array to callback

Tags: javascript, callback

how would you solve this: Update the transform function such that it works with n number elements and also same function works for string element ?

```js
const input = [
[2,3,5],
[2,4],
[7,8,9]
];

/*Edit only the transform */

const transform = (input, callback) => {
return callback([input[0],input[1]]);
}

/*Edit code only above */
   

const output = transform(input, (elm1, elm2) => {
return elm1.concat(elm2);// should return [7,8,9,2,4,2,3,5]
});

const input2 = ["hello", "welcome", !];

const output2 = transform(input2, (elm) => {
return elm.toUppercase(); // should return HELLO WELCOME !
});
```

Thank you all

Comment: Try adding "" to your ! element in last array if you get error on that spot.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you're not writing clear JavaScript code. Functional paradigms are your friend but units of work that aren't meaningful will only work against you. What benefit does your `transform` function provide, why is it better than calling the `cb` method directly on your data? Consider looking into `es6` array functions like `flatMap` and `reduce`.

```js
const input = [
    [2,3,5],
    [2,4],
    [7,8,9]
]

console.log(input.reduceRight((acc,cur) => acc.concat(cur), []))
// [7, 8, 9, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5]

console.log(["hello", "world"].map(str => str.toUpperCase()).join(" "))
//"HELLO WORLD"
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass the whole array to your `transform` function.

- For the first output => flat the arrays using `flat(Infinity)`
- For the second output => 'merge' all array value using `join` and then apply `toUpperCase` to the whole string:

```js
const input = [
  [2,3,5],
  [2,4],
  [7,8,9]
];

const transform = (input, callback) => {
  return callback(input);
}

const output = transform(input.reverse(), (elm1, elm2) => {
  return elm1.concat(elm2); // should return [7,8,9,2,4,2,3,5]
});

console.log(output.flat(Infinity).filter(Boolean));

const input2 = ["hello", " welcome", " !"];

const output2 = transform(input2, (elm) => {
  return elm.join('').toUpperCase(); // should return HELLO WELCOME !
});

console.log(output2);
```

Comment: Hi All,

Thank you so much for your help. 

Apologies for not being clear. I was allowed just to update :

const transform = (input, callback) => {
  return callback(input);
}

and not to touch any other output variables.